# What do $<111>$, $[010]$, $(111)$, and $\{100\}$ represents for a cubic crystal lattice?

Tags: solid-state-physics, definition, notation, crystals

I want to know the difference between different notations in crystal lattice. I know what Miller indices are but what does these four different notations really mean.

Comment: A quick Google will find you lots of articles on this, [for example this one](https://www.doitpoms.ac.uk/tlplib/miller_indices/bracket.php).